# What is the difference between doing data validation in the firebase database using rules vs front end?

Tags: swift, security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am learning to build a project using Firebase on iOS. I was looking at the [security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) page and I noticed the Data Validation using rules. So far, I have been doing the data validation in the front end (meaning doing the validation using Swift on my application).

There is also an example in the firebase document regarding data validation.I can do the same validation using swift also.

```
   {
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
    }
  }
}
```

What is the difference between these two data validation method?

What is the advantage or use case of when to use one over another?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Data validation on the front-end can be circumvented by malicious clients. Data validation on the server can not be avoided.

Data validation on the server requires a round-trip to the server. On the other hand: data validation on the client does not require a round-trip.

In general I'd recommend doing data validation both on the client and on the server. Data validation on the server guarantees that the data is valid, while data validation on the client ensures the best user experience.